# sql- display the table of records in the following format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

**Question Part 1**

I am having a Roles table which specifies the level and status of each candidate.

```
name     id     status      level       location     country
==========================================================
RAJ      1      PENDING      MAJOR      BANGALORE     INDIA   
SAM      2      ACTIVE       LEAD       KOLKATA       INDIA
ANN      3      CLOSED       SENIOR     HYDERABAD     INDIA
BEN      4      APPROVED     MINOR      PUNE          INDIA
JACK     5      APPROVED     MINOR      PUNE          INDIA
REC      6      ACTIVE       LEAD       BANGALORE     INDIA
VESPER   7      ACTIVE       LEAD       BANGALORE     INDIA
KISHOR   8      ACTIVE       LEAD       HYDERABAD     INDIA
```

I need to generate a report for count of candidtes in each level and how many are there
in particlular status based on the selected location and country. I may not be able to explain clearly. but i hope the below picture will help you to assist me.

```
status     MINOR   MAJOR   LEAD   SENIOR   Total 
==========================================================
PENDING    0       1       0      0        1
ACTIVE     0       0       4      0        4
CLOSED     0       0       0      1        1  
APPROVED   2       0       0      0        2
```

**Question Part 2**

How can I rename the values in status column that are displayed after executing above query. Suppose I want to display status Pending as 'Delayed response', Active as 'Online'.

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH PivotSource AS
(
SELECT id,status,LEVEL
FROM Roles
)
SELECT status,
       MINOR,
       MAJOR,
       LEAD,
       SENIOR,
       MINOR+MAJOR+LEAD+SENIOR AS Total
FROM PivotSource
PIVOT (COUNT(id) FOR LEVEL IN (MINOR,MAJOR,LEAD,SENIOR) ) AS Pvt;
```

Comment: I thank you very much for your quick and accurate solution. This solution has worked for me.

Comment: How can i rename the values in status column that are displayed after executing above query. suppose i want to display status-Pending as 'Delayed response', Active as 'Online'.

Answer (score 1):

A PIVOT-less solution:

```
SELECT
  status,
  MINOR  = COUNT(CASE level WHEN 'MINOR'  THEN 1 END),
  MAJOR  = COUNT(CASE level WHEN 'MAJOR'  THEN 1 END),
  LEAD   = COUNT(CASE level WHEN 'LEAD'   THEN 1 END),
  SENIOR = COUNT(CASE level WHEN 'SENIOR' THEN 1 END),
  Total  = COUNT(*)
FROM Roles
GROUP BY status
```

Comment: I thank you very much for your quick and accurate solution. This solution has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a pivot table. Here is an example:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/

Answer (score 0):

regarding Question Part 2:

```
WITH PivotSource AS ( SELECT id,status,LEVEL FROM Roles ) SELECT 
Status= case Status when 'Pending' then 'Delayed Response'
        when 'Active' then 'online'  
         else 'unknown' End,
MINOR,MAJOR,LEAD, SENIOR,MINOR+MAJOR+LEAD+SENIOR AS Total
FROM PivotSource
PIVOT (COUNT(id) FOR LEVEL IN (MINOR,MAJOR,LEAD,SENIOR) ) AS Pvt;
```

Comment: normally if you have additional questions, you can ask a new question in Stackoverflow, or as in this case add it to your original question. Don't add an "answer" to ask additional questions. Cheers! :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did not intend to ask a question. i wanted to update the answer.